# Qt: Safe parsing of Windows format data under Linux

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Server-Client application in which JSON data is send between those. The Client has a Linux and a Windows version, while the Server application runs under Linux.
The Linux Client communicates just find, but I have problems with the Windows Client.

The problematic JSON data contains a text field with an apostrophe. Let's say the content is "a dog`s name", then the Windows client sends this as "a dog\x92s name", while the Linux client goes for "a dog\xE2\x80\x99s name", at least that is what `qDebug()` shows me.

I parse the JSON data with the lines

```
    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(body);

    if(document.isArray()) json_data = document.array();
    if(document.isObject()) json_data.append(document.object());
```

where `body` is a `QByteArray` and `json_data` is a `QJsonArray`.

If the Windows data is fed into this, it seems that the Qt JSON parser does not recognize it as valid JSON and thus `json_data` end up being empty.

I really don't want to do anything manually with that text specific to those very characters, as I want it not only to work with that apostrophe but with all kinds of special characters that a user might enter in general. Is there some way to handle this in general? I assume the Windows is in something like the Windows-1252 encoding?

Comment: Maybe it worth to fix rather the clients and not the server? They seem to send different strings. By the way, the apostrophe symbol is `'`, and not `.

Comment: @vahancho Okay, yeah, "grave accent" would be the right term. Fixing on client side would also be fine, although I'd prefer it on server side - it is a REST based system and technically it would be legitimate to use a browser to communicate with the server. Plus, whatever fix I do at client side, I could also use at server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think windows client sends strings encoded in `CP1251` or `CP1252`. And json decoder expects `utf-8`.

Maybe source code is not in `utf-8` and has string literals. Qt4 has `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings`. Qt5 assume string literals encoded in `utf-8`.

```sh
$ echo -n "’" | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1251 | xxd
00000000: 92
$ echo -n "’" | xxd
00000000: e280 99
```

If you don't want to fix windows client the proper way (fixing it's output encoding) you can deal with this situation by converting all input from windows client to unicode before building `QJsonDocument` on server.

```cpp
QByteArray bodycp1252;
QTextCodec* cp1252 = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1252");
QTextCodec* utf8 = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QByteArray body = utf8->fromUnicode(cp1252->toUnicode(bodycp1252));
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(body);
```

It's possible to check if `QByteArray` contains valid `utf-8` data with `QUtf8::isValidUtf8(const char *chars, qsizetype len)` function. It is defined in private headers, so you need to add `QT += core-private`. Unfortunately implementation is not visible by linker (not exported from QtCore.lib) so you need to add [qutfcodec.cpp](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/codecs/qutfcodec.cpp?h=v5.15.2) from qt sources to your project to resolve linker errors.

```cpp
////////////////// is-valid-utf8.pro

QT -= gui

QT += core core-private

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

qt_src = "C:/Qt/5.15.1/Src"

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        $$qt_src/qtbase/src/corelib/codecs/qutfcodec.cpp

////////////////// main.cpp

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <private/qutfcodec_p.h>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QDebug>

bool isValidUtf8(const QByteArray& data) {
    return QUtf8::isValidUtf8(data.data(), data.size()).isValidUtf8;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextCodec* utf8 = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QTextCodec* cp1251 = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1251");

    QByteArray utf8data1 = utf8->fromUnicode("Привет мир");
    QByteArray cp1251data1 = cp1251->fromUnicode("Привет мир");

    QByteArray utf8data2 = utf8->fromUnicode("Hello world");
    QByteArray cp1251data2 = cp1251->fromUnicode("Hello world");

    Q_ASSERT(isValidUtf8(utf8data1));
    Q_ASSERT(isValidUtf8(cp1251data1) == false);

    Q_ASSERT(isValidUtf8(utf8data2));
    Q_ASSERT(isValidUtf8(cp1251data2));

    qDebug() << "test passed";

    return 0;
}
```

[source](https://github.com/mugiseyebrows/is-valid-utf8)

Comment: Hmm, I think for my first test I simply try to convert if my array is empty after my initial code instead of going for that unlinked part of code.

Comment: My final code is made to do three attempts. First try to parse normal, and check if the document `isNull`. If so, try it with your code as second attempt. If it still didn't work, throw out anything that is not ASCII (not ideal, but acceptable). For each failed attempt, the data in the error object is printed to the programs logfile. Thank you for your code.